# Git Development-Test-Production branches proccess

Tags: git, merge, version-control, branch, git-checkout

I am interesting in this process:

First I'd like to make any in my **development branch**, than it should be pushed **to Test (master) branch** and, therefore, to **production**.

For me the process:

1. **init commit**
   then, make prod branch from master init commit
   then, make dev branch from master init commit
2. **checkout to dev branch**
   then, do any
   then, commit
   then, checkout to master
   then, merge with dev
3. **Do tests**
   then, commit
   then, checkout to prod
   then, merge with master

Is this a right way to use this way or not? If not, explain please the right process.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'd recommend to read this first https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/ and http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html

Comment: 'git help everyday' and 'git help workflows' have some good examples.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for something similar to the [git flow workflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).
Read all about it in the following post by ***`Vincent Driessen`***

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir !

Comment: Sure, Please be kind enough to accept and vote for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

That would well if you don't have may feature to develop in parallel.

If you do and said features needs to be integrated, then the [gitworkflow (one word)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57175304/6309) is a better fit.

[image: gitworkflow]

The main advantage is that you can merge multiple feature branch, and then decide to remove some of them (because they are still too buggy, not ready)